# Why "Unlock keyring" appears after installing Ubuntu One?

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, lubuntu, keyrings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “Unlock keyring” and how do I get rid of it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184266/what-is-unlock-keyring-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it)

Never had this message upon log-in before installing Ubuntu One.

[image]

Can I use Ubuntu One and avoid being prompted each time like this?

(Ubuntu One is set not to start with the session.)

I use Lubuntu 12.04

Comment: it was not a duplicate before the edit to merge them was made

Comment: The two questions were very similar and to answer the one about how to get rid of the dialog would have meant to answer the other too. We will see, what the community hast to say. In my opinion they're still duplicates. Also as we see in the other question, it might be a bug.

Comment: in my opinion was important to elucidate why without warning and without me wishing or acting in this sense, ubuntu one activates the use of keyring. i never use keyring. maybe i'll try to re-edit that unified question to emphasize this

Comment: Ubuntu one activates the use of the keyring because that's where it stores its credentials. If you want, you can make your keyring open automatically if what bothers you is the prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyring is made to store your passwords (ex Ubuntu One passwd) so you just have to unlock keyring and you dont have enter password stored in keyring.

Comment: is made to - but it does it without me asking - and why did it not appear before installing ubuntuone