# Is there a "Passwords and Keys" dialogue in Lubuntu desktop?

Tags: lubuntu, menu, keyrings

Getting [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/184268/47206), it seems that there must be a  "Passwords and Keys" dialogue in Lubuntu, but I cannot see a button for it in my menus nor in /usr/share/applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably You don't have this application installed. To install "Passwords and Keys" type:

`sudo apt-get install seahorse`

Comment: is  it the same with this: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/seahorse/

Comment: yes it is same package